# Best way for waiting for nested object data to be available in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object with nested objects like so:

```
{
  key_1: 'data',
  key_2: 'data',
  nested_1: {some_data...}
  nested_2: {some_data...}
},
{
  key_1: 'data',
  key_2: 'data',
  nested_1: {some_data...}
  nested_2: {some_data...}
},
...
```

There is some processing that creates this object, lets say **nested_1** takes a little longer to process than the rest. I have some code that maps through this object and nested objects, but **nested_1** is undefined at that moment.

```
const myItems = myNestedObjects.map((mno) => {
    if (mno.key_1 == 'ACTIVE' && mno.nested_1.some_key) {
        // Do some stuff
    }
    else  {
        // Do some different stuff
    }

    return {
        // some stuff
    }
})
```

What is the best way to wait for this to object to be ready and map through?

Answer (score 1):

```
const myItems = myNestedObjects.map(item => {
if (item.key_1 == 'ACTIVE' && item.nested_1 instanceof Object) {
    // Do some stuff
}
else  {
    // Do some different stuff
}

return {
    // some stuff
}
})
```

Comment: Add explanation for whatever answer you write